# Changing session variable

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I've built a small CMS, it has a page where you can edit the profile settings. The trouble that I'm having is that when the user changes his username, the FORM where all the previous values are shown crashes and shows that all variables are undefined.

It happens because all user values are pulled out of the database with the users username that is cached in a SESSION . When you edit the username the SESSION variable still has the old value. How can you give it the new one?

I hope this is clear. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `$_SESSION['username'] = $newname`? It's just an array like any other... assign the new name in there.

Comment: @castis there isn't much code to add, as it would be useless. I would have to paste a huge form here.

Comment: suggest you using userId while not username as the index